# Relation between dimension of Proj(S) and dimension of S

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be Noetherian standard ${\mathbb{N}}^r$ graded ring where $S_{\underline{0}}$ is an Aritinian local ring.

$$Proj(S)=\lbrace{P\in Spec S | S_{++}\not\subseteq P, P\hspace{0.1cm} homogeneous}\rbrace.$$ Then what are the relations between dim(Proj(S)) and dim(S) and max$\lbrace dim\frac{S}{P}|P\in Proj(S) \rbrace.$

I know that $dim(Proj(S))=max\lbrace dim\frac{S}{P}|P\in Proj(S) \rbrace-r.$

Comment: In the definition of Proj, don't you want $P$ to be graded?

Comment: yes, P is homogeneous

Comment: What does it mean by standard $\mathbb{N}^r$-graded? I mean which degree pieces do you refer to by standard?

Comment: S_{e_i} over S_{0} where e_i=(0,...,1,...0) 1 is at ith position.